# UnicodeEncodeError when installing Brightway2 under Python 2.7

Tags: python, pip, brightway

**Anaconda Python2.7**

**Ubuntu16.04 LTS**

I have UnicodeEncodeError when installing [Brightway2](https://brightwaylca.org/) by:

```
pip install brightway2
```

The UnicodeEncondeError:

```
Collecting brightway2
Using cached brightway2-2.0.2.tar.gz
Collecting appdirs (from brightway2)
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asteval (from brightway2)
  Using cached asteval-0.9.8.tar.gz
Collecting bw2analyzer>=0.9 (from brightway2)
  Using cached bw2analyzer-0.9.1.tar.gz
Collecting bw2calc>=1.2.1 (from brightway2)
  Using cached bw2calc-1.5.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/bw2calc.egg-info
writing requirements to pip-egg-info/bw2calc.egg-info/requires.txt
writing pip-egg-info/bw2calc.egg-info/PKG-INFO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ikaXlZ/bw2calc/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Visualization',
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 272, in run
    writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 600, in write_pkg_info
    metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 1106, in write_pkg_info
    self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)
  File "/home/runsheng/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 51, in write_pkg_file
    file.write('License: %s\n' % self.get_license())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ikaXlZ/bw2calc/
```

It only happens under Python2.7. When I switch to Python3.5 the error disappears and brightway2 works fine.

I have installed *ftfy* and *eight* to translate code between Python2.7 and Python3.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/984). In the meantime, I have released a [new version of bw2calc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bw2calc/) that [should fix this problem](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/commits/adb245ccd2c643689505a96ebd2c3943295bb3ee).